# is digit doesn't return true on int array elements

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

```
void* checkRow(void* in)
{
    //pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
    parameters* temp = (parameters*) in;
    int row = temp->row;
    int col = temp-> col;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = row; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (j = col; j< SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", isdigit(temp->arr[i][j]));
            if(isdigit(temp->arr[i][j]) && temp->arr[i][j] <= SIZE)
            {
                //pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
                return (void*) 1;
            }
        }

    return (void*) 0;
}
```

For some reason why i try to function `isdigit(temp->arr[i][j])` alway return false instead of true. the array was initialize with all numbers. I ran a printf on the array and it indicate that the array return correct the result, so I don't know why isdigit does not recognize array's elements as digits.

the array is a member of a structure

```
typedef struct
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int arr[SIZE][SIZE];
}parameters;
```

Comment: *the array was initialize with all numbers*. Did you initialize them with numbers like `1`, or characters like `'1'`? You need to use the latter not the former in order to get `isdigit()` to return true.

Comment: I initialize it with 1 as in integer.

Comment: That's the problem. You can convert numbers to their character representations by adding `'0'` to them.

Comment: oh, I see, then I guess ill try a different approach then

Comment: @wolfhead321wolfhead321 this MIGHT be an *xy-problem*. What exactly do you expect `isdigit()` to return here? Maybe describe something, that *is* an `int` but you don't want to consider it "valid" ...

Comment: yes Im trying to check whether a solution for sudoku of size 9x9 is valid or not, My other approach is to create a temporary array  of size 0, and then assign element of array to a holder then check if `temparr[holder] == 0 `

Comment: @wolfhead321wolfhead321, you cannot create a zero-length array, and if you could, it would not have any elements to assign anything to.  Do you perhaps just want `(0 < temp->arr[i][j]) && (temp->arr[i][j] <= SIZE)` ?

Comment: Still don't get it. Please give an example for an input value where the `isdigit()` -- *as used in your code* -- should evaluate to logical `false`.

Comment: sorry, this is my mistake. I was suppose to check if elements in role was unique(from 1-9), but instead i checked wether elements are digit.

Comment: In this `if(isdigit(temp->arr[i][j]) && temp->arr[i][j] <= SIZE)` you are mixing `char` range checking with `int` range checking. Why don't you write `if(temp->arr[i][j] > 0 && temp->arr[i][j] <= SIZE)`?

Comment: The `isdigit`, etc. functions are in file `c(haracter)type.h` and are called "**character** classification functions" for a reason. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1 Did you not wonder what `isalpha()` would do with an normal integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isdigit(int)` needs a value in the range of `unsigned char` or `EOF`, else it is undefined behavior.  If `char` is signed, then `isdigit(int)` using a negative `char` value is problematic.

`isdigit(int)` returns true when the value is in the range `'0'` ... `'9'`.  The numeric values of these consonants are typically 48 to 57", but it is character set dependent - ASCII being the most common.   The 10 values must be consecutive.

To convert a number to a textual digit, use `x + '0'`

To test for a textual digit and to avoid using `isdigit()` with its limited range, use:

```
int test_isdigit(int x) {
   return x >= '0' && x <= '9';
}
```

This is portable.

Answer (score 1):

Click here for documentation of [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)..

isdigit(int) actually needs a `char` value. It returns whether the input `char` value is lies between 48 to 57(ASCII values of 0-9).

So if you need to check whether `temp->arr[i][j]` is a digit, you can use eight `isdigit(48 + temp->arr[i][j])` or `isdigit('0' + temp->arr[i][j])`.

`arr` is actually a integer array. So you can't store any other type of variable in `arr`. What is the point of checking..? You can use this to check whether there is only one digit in an element of the array..